# Finding the maximum occurring string within a text file

Tags: php, html, text, flat-file

So I've seen questions asked before that are along the lines of finding the maximum occurence of a string within a file but all of those rely on knowing what to look for.

I have what you might almost call a flat file database that grabs a bunch of input data and basically wraps different parts of it in html span tags with referencing ids.

Each line comes out in this kind of fashion:

```
<p>
<span class="ip">58.106.**.***</span> 
Wrote <span class='text'>some text</span>
<span class='effect1'> and caused seizures </span>
<span class='time'>23:47</span> 
</p>
```

How would I then go about finding the #test contents that occurs the most times.

i.e if I had

```
<p>
    <span class="ip">58.106.**.***</span> 
    Wrote <span id='text'>woof</span>
    <span class='effect1'> and caused seizures </span>
    <span class='time'>23:47</span> 
    </p>

<p>
    <span class="ip">58.106.**.***</span> 
    Wrote <span class='text'>meow</span>
    <span class='effect1'> and caused mind-splosion </span>
    <span class='time'>23:47</span> 
    </p>

<p>
    <span class="ip">58.106.**.***</span> 
    Wrote <span class='text'>meow</span>
    <span class='effect1'> and used no effect </span>
    <span class='time'>23:47</span> 
    </p>

<p>
    <span class="ip">58.106.**.***</span> 
    Wrote <span class='text'>meow</span>
    <span class='effect1'> and used no effect </span>
    <span class='time'>23:47</span> 
    </p>
```

the output would be 'meow'.

How would I accomplish this in php?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off: Your format is not conducive to this type of data manipulation; you might want to consider changing it.

That said, based on this structure the logical solution would be to leverage `DOMXPath` as Dani says. This could have been problematic because of all the duplicate `id`s in there, but in practice it works (*after emitting a boatload of warnings*, which is one more reason that the data structure affords revision).

Here's some code to go with the idea:

```
$input = '<body>'.get_input().'</body>';
$doc = new DOMDocument;
$doc->loadHTML($input); // lots of warnings, duplicate ids!
$xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);
$result = $xpath->query("//*[@id='text']/text()");

$occurrences = array();
foreach ($result as $item) {
    if (!isset($occurrences[$item->wholeText])) {
        $occurrences[$item->wholeText] = 0;
    }
    $occurrences[$item->wholeText]++;
}

// Sort the results and produce final answer    
arsort($occurrences);
reset($occurrences);

echo "The most common text is '".key($occurrences).
     "', which occurs ".current($occurrences)." times.";
```

**[See it in action](http://codepad.viper-7.com/CuMZLv)**.

**Update** (seeing as you fixed the duplicate id issue): You would simply change the xpath query to `"//*[@class='text']/text()"` so that it continues to match. However this way of doing things remains inefficient, so if one or more of these apply:

- you are going to do this all the time
- you have lots of data
- you need it to be really fast

then changing the data format is a good idea.

Comment: Yep i fixed the issue with the id's (need to sleep more haha) and this is amazing thanks a tonne, I don't have to load the input into the page that i'm in though do i? can i not simply reference the text file with something like file_get_contents($filename)?

Comment: I don't need it to be really fast but it would certainly be a bonus, and the other two apply aswell :S but I want to keep it in html/text format and be able to reference the individual elements.

Comment: @MagicDev: Yes to the first comment. For the second, it all depends on what exactly your requirements are. I can't say without all the context you have.

Comment: Just need to be able to sort through client side with basic functions 
and be able to retrieve things specific to ip address; that's basically it.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [DOMXPath](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domxpath.php), you can use an XPath query to get all the `#text` and then find the most used one with php.
There is a problem that you used the same id few times which is not valid HTML so DOM might break.